# Continuity and $L^p$ norm

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

[image]

My questions : Why $G\circ u_n \rightarrow G\circ u$ in $L^{\infty}$ and $ (G'\circ u_n)u'_n \rightarrow (G'\circ u) u'$ in $L^p$?

I know the answer of $G$ Is Lips but in this case ?

Comment: You can use that $G$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[-2M,+2M]$.

Comment: I think that here we use the fact that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^{\infty}$ and therefore $\|u_n\|_{L^{\infty}}$ is bounded and we have done